# Is it safe to use celery acks_late with librabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, heartbeat

I want to use `acks_late=True` for some idempotent tasks, but I'm unsure how hard disconnections between the workers and RMQ are treated when there are no application heartbeats probing the connection.

[librabbitmq does not support heartbeats](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2312#issuecomment-60398464), but the pyampq libs do. I'm being cautious about what that means for acks_late, as I don't want messages sitting in the queue being "processed" forever.